# ffmpeg - filename numbering seems to generate error

Tags: ffmpeg

This is on Windows 10 and I have 3 files in the same folder named as follows:

- test-0.data
- test-1.data
- test-2.data

Said files are to be read using the option rawvideo and then saved as mp4.
My cli-command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt nv21 -s 640x480 -r 15 -i test-%d.data out3.mp4
```

but I get the following error:

```
test-%d.data: No such file or directory
```

If I try with a single file in the directory, it works fine:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt nv21 -s 640x480 -r 15 -i mike-1.data out4.mp4
```

I am at loss here and I am probably doing something stupid. Can someone please help to correct my cli-command?

Here is the full report:

```
ffmpeg started on 2016-09-12 at 23:47:56
Report written to "ffmpeg-20160912-234756.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt nv21 -s 640x480 -r 15 -i "test-%d.data" out3.mp4 -report
ffmpeg version N-81423-g61fac0e Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 54.100 / 57. 54.100
  libavformat    57. 47.101 / 57. 47.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 52.100 /  6. 52.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'rawvideo'.
Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument 'nv21'.
Reading option '-s' ... matched as option 's' (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument '640x480'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '15'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'test-%d.data'.
Reading option 'out3.mp4' ... matched as output file.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file test-%d.data.
Applying option f (force format) with argument rawvideo.
Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument nv21.
Applying option s (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument 640x480.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 15.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: test-%d.data.
[file @ 00000000006c7ae0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
test-%d.data: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` or `%0Nd` sequential pattern syntax is only used with certain (de)muxers, such as the [image file demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). This pattern cannot be used with any arbitrary input.

To concatenate rawvideo you can use the [concat protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -framerate 15 -video_size 640x480 -pixel_format nv21 -i "concat:test-0.data|test-1.data|test-2.data" output.mp4
```

- Note that the [rawvideo demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) uses `-framerate` instead of `-r`, `-pixel_format` instead of `-pix_fmt`, and `-video_size` instead of `-s`.
- For other input formats use the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) or [concat filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) instead since few formats can properly use the concat protocol.

Comment: Thx. Ok, that explains the error. But how can get one single output file? Do I need to open a new question?

Comment: @moster67 I was unclear if you were trying to concatenate when I wrote the answer. Answer updated with a concat example.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the double apastrophe, it has special meaning.

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt nv21 -s 640x480 -r 15 -i test-%d.data out3.mp4
```

Comment: That is weird. The double quotes are indeed shown in the report but when I run the command in the Command Prompt they are not present.